# Java 8 and annotation processor

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, androidx

According to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/DefaultLifecycleObserver) `DefaultLifecyclerObserver` is preferred over `LifecycleObserver` since the later uses annotations (if we are using Java 8)

> If you use Java 8 language, always prefer it over annotations.

Can someone please explain why this is so?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the main reason why `DefaultLifecyclerObserver` was stated as preferred.

Imagine you implemented the `LifecycleObserver` interface and use the `OnLifecycleEvent` annotations:

```
class MyLifeCycleObserver(val lifeCycle: Lifecycle) : LifecycleObserver {
  @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
   fun onCreated() {
    //...
   }
  @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
   fun onResumed() {
    //...
   }
}
```

You can notice from the above that for every `@OnLifecycleEvent` annotation we have to pass a `Lifecycle.Event` which forces many developers to always try to recall what to pass, how to pass, and where to pass an event. This is actually an overhead which brings about the need for a default interface (`DefaultLifecyclerObserver`).

How about now?

```
class MyLifeCycleObserver : DefaultLifecycleObserver {

     override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
         //...
     }
     override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
         //...
     }
 }
```

> Cleaner, better and more reliable

**Why is it specific to Java 8 ?**

> Java 8 allows developers to use what is called [Default Method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-methods-java/) or
>   [Defender methods](https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-default-methods) feature, which enables the adding of new methods to
>   an interface without breaking its existing implementation.

Comment: Why is this Java 8 specific then?

Comment: why do you say its `more reliable`?